# Scala/Spark : How to perform filter and change value of a column for a list of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

1) I have a DF with several columns but the most important ones are "col1", "col2" .... "col10" (10 columns). I'm only interested in the rows where at least ONE of these columns have value > 1. What I have now is:

```
DF.filter(col(col1) > 1 or col(col2) > 1 or col(col3) > 1 or col(col4) > 1 or col(col5) > 1   
          or col(col6) > 1 or col(col7) > 1 or col(col8) > 1 or col(col9) > 1 or col(col10) > 1)
```

2) Similar to #1 , I have another DF where I need to subtract by 1 the value of a list of columns

```
 DF
  .withColumn("col1", col("col1") - 1)
  .withColumn("col2", col("col2") - 1)
  .withColumn("col3", col("col3") - 1)
  .withColumn("col4", col("col4") - 1)
   // and so on .....
```

Both these work but is there a more elegant way to work with multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list of the columns of interest and use `reduce` to assemble the repetitive `or` condition in the `where` clause:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4),
  (102, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
).toDF("id", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")

val colList = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("c"))

df.where(colList.map(col(_) > 1).reduce(_ || _)).show
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// | id| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// |102| -1|  0|  1|  2|  3|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

For repetitive `withColumn` transformations, consider using `foldLeft`:

```
colList.foldLeft(df)((acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, col(c) - 1)).show
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// | id| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// |101| -1| -2| -3| -4| -5|
// |102| -2| -1|  0|  1|  2|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

However, rather than using repetitive `withColumn` it would be more efficient to perform the subtraction across the columns as elements of an `ArrayType` column in one transformation:

```
df.
  withColumn("arr", array(colList.map(col(_) - 1): _*)).
  select($"id" +: (0 until colList.size).map(i => $"arr"(i).as(colList(i))): _*)
```